# Minimum and maximum with lagrange multiplier

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I have a function with two constraints whose intersection is unitary circumference. 
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$ and $$x+y+z=0$$
I can't understand why I cannot apply the lagrange multipliers method with only the intersection as constraints. When I have two constraints, I am restricting the domain of the function to the points that satify $g_1(X)=0$ and $g_2(X)=0$ so I can't understand why I just can't replace the two zero sets with the intersection set.

Could you help me?
The correct lagrangian should be $$L(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)=f(x,y,z)-\lambda (x^2+y^2+z^2-1)-\mu(x+y+z)$$
but I wish to understand why studying $$L(x,y,z,\lambda)=f(x,y,z)-\lambda (x^2+y^2-1)$$ is wrong.
Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a too general question. You should give explicitely the different constraints you have e;g. $g_1(x,y)=x^2+y^2-3x+2y-7=0$n $g_2(x,y)=...$...AND the way you express the lagrangian. The only answer that can be given to your request **in its present state** is that if you replace your 2 constraints by only one, and if you do not re-use one of them later, you will probably reach a solution which is the solution to another "poorer" issue.

Comment: @JeanMarie updated question :)

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^3$, $x^2+y^2 = 1$ is a cylinder, not a circle. Anyway, the intersection is not the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1, z=0$.

Comment: The intersection of the unit sphere  (your first equation) and à plane (your 2nd equation) is a  circle in 3D space but not the unit circle in the xOy plane

Comment: ok @JeanMarie others have already pointed out that. I think that this doesn't answer my theoretical question: in general can I replace nn constraints with their intersection?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that $x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0$ is **not** the intersection of your two constraints.  In fact it has only two points in common with that intersection.

Comment: but in general can I replace $n$ constraints with their intersection?